# post json data with php curl for multipart/form-data for file upload vía cakephp 2

Tags: json, rest, cakephp, curl, multipartform-data

i want to post json data with php curl for a multipart/form-data with a file upload field.
i tried this in cakephp 2 in a action:

```
public function json_post(){

    $this->autoRender = false;
    debug('json post test');

    $data = array('Post' => array(
        'subject' => 'test subject content',
        'body' => 'test body content'
        'fileName' => '/Users/mar/Pictures/cow_wall_90.jpg'
    ));                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

    $ch = curl_init('http://www.mydomain.com/posts/phone_upload.json');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            //'Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    debug($result); 


}
```

fileName is the equivalent for the file upload field in a form.
subject and body are the equivalent for text fields in a form.
i miss something may be in the data array or in the Content-Type but can't find the problem.

thanks for any help, regards, martin

Answer (score 0):

From http://dtbaker.net/web-development/uploading-a-file-using-curl-in-php/:
**notice the @ infront of the file path, this is the magic part.**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
    $post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Seems you were missing the magic part.

You may also switch from cURL to CakePHP's HttpSocket, but that's just personal prefrence.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html

Comment: thank you, thats it. I also switched to CakePHP's HttpSocket.

Comment: can you show the HttpSocket equivalent of curl to "put" json data ?

Comment: @Divyanshu http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html#HttpSocket::put